# When the session timeout,how can I get the session info by using beaker in bottle

Tags: session, bottle

I use beaker for session in bottle,and when someone login I recode the username to session.Like:

```
s = request.environ.get('beaker.session') 
s["user"] = "someone"
```

Then here is the situation I encountered:

I set the session.timeout:1800,that means 30 mins later the session will be timeout.When the session timeout.I want to get the value of s["user"] so that I can do something with this value.

In a word,if I can catch something when beaker.session is ready to timeout.